# Is $n=6$ the only integer satisfying phenomenal properties in number theory ? if yes then why?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, perfect-numbers

From the  [background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6) I read about the properties of  integer $n=6$ ,I find that its satisfying many interesting properties , In particular in number theory , $n=6$  is the first perfect number and all prime numer are of the form $ 6m+1 \text{or} 6m-1$, $n=6$ is the only multiperfect number wich satisfying periodicity with small period , The solution of fermat last theorem for rational exponent need the denominator  to be divisible by 6, and one can check this [background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6) about group theory and others area of mathematics  He would find a huge property of that integer , My question here is :Is $n=6$ the only integer satisfying phenomenal properties in number theory ?if yes then why ?

Comment: What are Bizzard properties?

Comment: I meant rare properties or formidable or mirical properties

Comment: @saulspatz, Probably the good word , is phenomenal , sorry for my bad english

Comment: You might be interested in the "Strong law of small numbers" - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers . "There aren't enough small numbers to meet the many demands made of them." You can list the unique properties of pretty much any small enough number and it looks surprising ...

Comment: $42$ has amazing properties, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138886/which-integers-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-three-cubes-in-infinitely-many-ways). And it is the "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything". So $$42 = 80435758145817515^3 - 80538738812075974^3 +  12602123297335631^3$$

Comment: $2$ and $3$ are not of the form $6m\pm 1$.

Comment: [$24$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_(number)) is a semiperfect number and also has wonderful properties in number theory; e.g., it is the only number whose divisors — $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24$ — are exactly those numbers $n$ for which every invertible element of the commutative ring $\mathbb  Z/n\mathbb Z $ is a square root of $1$

Comment: All prime numbers (except for 2 itself) are of the form $2m+1$, and there is no exception such as 3 for $6m\pm1$. The number 2 has also other phenomenal properties. For example it is the least positive even integer.

Comment: and the only even prime